# How to prove a positive matrix's spectral radius strictly increases as its dimension increases?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, normed-spaces, spectral-radius

Consider a positive matrix sequence $\{M_1, M_2, \cdots, M_k\}$ where $M_{1} = \begin{bmatrix}x_{1, 1}\end{bmatrix}$, $M_2 = \begin{bmatrix} x_{1, 1} & x_{1, 2} \\ x_{2, 1} & x_{2, 2}\end{bmatrix}$, $\cdots$, $M_k = \begin{bmatrix} x_{1, 1} & x_{1, 2} & \cdots & x_{1, k} \\x_{2, 1} & x_{2, 2} & \cdots & x_{2, k} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ x_{k, 1} & x_{k, 2} & \cdots & x_{k, k} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}p & p & p& \cdots & p & p \\
p^2 & p(1+p) & p(1+p) & \cdots & p(1+p) & p(1+p) \\ 
p^2(1+p) & p^2(2+p) & p(1+p)^2 & \cdots & p(1+p)^2 &p(1+p)^2\\ 
p^2(1+p)^2 & p^2(1+p)(2+p) & p(1+p)^3 - p & \cdots & p(1+p)^3& p(1+p)^3 \\
p^2(1+p)^3 & p^2(1+p)^2(2+p) & p(1+p)^4 - p(1+p) & \cdots & p(1+p)^4& p(1+p)^4 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
p^2(1+p)^{k-2} & p^2(1+p)^{k-3}(2+p) & p(1+p)^{k-1} - p(1+p)^{k-4} & \cdots &p(1+p)^{k-1} - p & p(1+p)^{k-1}\end{bmatrix}$, where $ p> 0$ and thus $x_{i, j} > 0, \forall i, j=1, 2, \cdots, k$.
**we want to show that the spectral radius is strictly increasing, i.e. $\rho(M_{d}) < \rho(M_{d+1}), \forall d=1, 2, \cdots, k-1$.**  Also we are interested in the changes of smallest eigenvalue, can we show that they are decreasing?

---

Now I know $x_{i, 1} < x_{i, 2} < x_{i, k}, \forall i=1, 2, \cdots, k$, so $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{d}x_{j, 1} \leq \rho(M_d) \leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{d}x_{j, d}, \forall d=1, 2, \cdots, k $, but $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{d}x_{j, d} > \sum\limits_{j=1}^{d+1}x_{j, 1}$ sometimes, so I cannot use this relation to show $\rho(M_d) < \rho(M_{d+1})$.

---

Is there any other ways to show the strictly increasing spectral radius?

Comment: What exactly do you know about the entries besides that they are positive? It sounds like the entries are increasing as you move left to right across each row, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I can give the closed-form of the matrix.

Comment: The closed-form for every matrix have been added. Is this a special matrix that has been well studied?

Comment: I cannot totally see what $x_{i,j}$ is from this way of writing it. It looks like the first $i$ entries in row $i$ are unique and then the rest are the same as the $i$th entry. In any case this is extremely far off from being diagonally dominant so that idea is very much out the window. It's not symmetric either; do you happen to know if it is symmetrizable, i.e. if there exists a positive definite $A_k$ such that $A_k M_k A_k$ is symmetric?